# Remove automatically generated Facebook Page using my business name

Tags: facebook

I found a page on Facebook that has my business name on it and a message like this:

> This Page is automatically generated based on what Facebook users are interested in

But I absolutely don't need that and want to remove it. I don't have a page for my business on Facebook and I don't intend to have one either. What can I do? This is a serious violation of users privacy.

Comment: I don't see how this is a violation of anyone's privacy. The data is obviously either publicly available or added by Facebook users.

Comment: Because it is MY COMPANY and if I didnt publish it on Facebook is because I DONT WANT IT to be on Facebook so nobody else has the right to do it either.

Answer (score 1):

Basic details of a business can be added by users across Facebook without any permission and Facebook would generate a page for it when enough people post and show interest in a certain place/business.

To report a Page:

1. Go to the Page you want to report
2. Hover over More below the Page's
   cover photo
3. Select Report Page Choose the option that best describes
   the issue and follow the on-screen instructions

Or see this page for more help on reporting something on Facebook: https://www.facebook.com/help/263149623790594/?helpref=hc_fnav

The common procedure to deal with anything on Facebook is to find a "Report" link and go through it.

Comment: I had already reported it but there is no option that properly describes the situation so I dont think its gonna do any good.

Comment: Whose privacy is being violated?    Is the page attached to your account in any way?    If not, then it's certainly not your privacy.

Comment: Reporting to the page is not going to help. There is no official solution for this yet.

Comment: Because it is a page about MY COMPANY and I didnt authorize it so yes, it is a violation of my privacy.